# Linux Timing across Kernel & User Space

Tags: c++, linux, time, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a kernel module for a special camera, working through V4L2 to handle transfer of frames to userspace code.. Then I do lots of userspace stuff in the app..

Timing is very critical here, so I've been doing lots of performance profiling and plain old `std::chrono::steady_clock` stuff to track timing, but I've reached the point where I need to also collect timing data from the Kernel side of things so that I can analyze the entire path from hardware interrupt through V4L DQBuf to userspace...

Can anyone recommend a good way to get high-resolution timing data, that would be consistent with application userspace data, that I could use for such comparisons?   Right now I'm measuring activity in microseconds..

*Ubuntu 12.04 LTS*

Answer (score 1):

At the lowest level, there are the `rdtsc` and `rdtscp` instructions if you're on an x86/x86-64 processor.  That should provide the lowest overhead, highest possible resolution across the kernel/userspace boundary.

*However*, there are things you need to worry about.  You need to make sure you're executing across the same core/cpu, the process isn't being context switched, and the frequency isn't changing across invocations.  If the cpu supports an invariant tsc, (`constant_tsc` in `/proc/cpuinfo`) it's a little more reliable across cpus/cores and frequencies.

This should provide roughly nanosecond accuracy.

Comment: @Yeraze:  You can remove some of the problems mentioned by Jason by setting CPU affinities for the device driver and application.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of kernel level utilities available that can get the timing related traces for you. For eg `ptrace`, `ftrace`, `LTTng`, `Kprobes`. Check out this link for more information.
http://elinux.org/Kernel_Trace_Systems